# Uniqueness and existence of solution $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{x-y}$ given $y(2)=2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I want to determine if there exists a solution and the uniqueness of it for: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{x-y}$ given $y(2)=2$

A solution said that we cannot determine if there exists a solution since it was discontinuous at (2,2). This solution seems to imply that it is possible for x to be a number for example 1.99 and y be 2.00 or x be 2.00 and y be 2.01. I'm confused as to why the textbook makes this sort of assumption - I thought we were just determining the continuity of the point.

If we were to look at the neighborhood then why then if we are given $y(2)=1$ as the condition that we know that the above has a solution? It seems arbitrary as to how far we can go left and right or above and down a certain point to say that it was not continuous?

Comment: the initial conditions tell you that $y'(2)=0$, but you would want to solve a differential equation, and the initial substitution i would make is $f(x)=y(x)-x$ and the try to solve in terms of $f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that (at least if you want real solutions) the solution is only defined for $x \ge 2$.

Strictly speaking the solution is not a solution at $x=2$, as writing $y' = \ldots$ implies that $y$ is differentiable, and a function differentiable at $x=2$ must be defined in $(2-\epsilon, 2+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. If $y$ was a solution
in a neighbourhood of $x=2$ with $y(2)=2$, we'd have $y'(2)=0$, and then $x-y < 0$ for
$x < 2$ with $|x-2|$ sufficiently small.  But then $\sqrt{x-y}$ is not real.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the hypothesis $\lvert \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\rvert<M$ in the nbd. of $(x_0,y_0)$ of Picard's uniqueness theorem doesn't hold here, hence the theorem fails to conclude anything.

Rather you should look to find the solution by using the substitution $x-y=u$